# Use POST method to delete in GAE get 405 error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="/del/" >
     <input type="hidden" name="dealkey" value="{{deal.key()}}" />
     <input class="btn btn-small" type="submit" value="Delete"  />
 </form>

class Delete(Handler):
    def post(self):
        dealid = self.request.get('dealkey')
        dealid = int(dealid)
        if dealid:
            Book.delete(dealid)
            self.redirect("/book")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                            ('/book', BookMe),
                            ('/del/',Delete),
                            ],debug=True)
```

I am trying to use POST to delete entity in gae datastore, but i get 405, could anybody to explain it ?

Comment: I solved, the problem lies in the mapping area. i need to map /book/del/ not the /del/ to Delete handler

Answer (score 1):

How you define your `Handler`?

Or you can use the built-in handler and see if the error continue.

```
class Delete(webapp2.RequestHandler)
      def post(self):
          dealid = self.request.get('dealkey')
          dealid = int(dealid)
          if dealid:
              Book.delete(dealid)
              self.redirect("/book")
```